# Calling a method without an instance

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
class Cars
  attr_accessor :car_make
  attr_accessor :car_model
  def initialize(make, model)
    self.car_make = make
    self.car_model = model
  end
end
```

I would like to know if it is possible to implement a `list_cars` method
and call the method like so:

```
ford = Cars.new("Ford" ,"F-150")
honda = Cars.new("Honda", "CRV")
list_cars(ford, honda)
```

i.e., without necessarily calling it from an existing object. I tried this:

```
def list_cars(first_car, second_car)
  puts "My father has two cars - a #{first_car.car_make} #{first_car.car_model} and a #{second_car.car_make} #{second_car.car_model}."
end
```

I realize that this code is missing something, but I don't know what that is.

Comment: Your code should work - what error are you getting?

Comment: undefined method `list_cars' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

Comment: `list_cars` is implemented outside class `Cars` right? Your code works for me.

Comment: Yep, implemented outside the class.  Huh... that's weird!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it a class method:

```
class Cars
  def self.list_cars(first_car, second_car)
    puts "My father has two cars - a #{first_car.car_make} #{first_car.car_model} and a #{second_car.car_make} #{second_car.car_model}."
  end
end
```

Then you can call it simply by:

```
Cars.list_cars(car1, car2)
```

You can find more about class methods [at rubymonk](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/45-more-classes/lessons/113-class-variables).

If this is the right way (or a new module, or as a method in object space) depends on your project architecture.

Comment: Ah perfect, that does it.  Thanks for the tip on the resource, too - I'm teaching myself...

Answer (score 1):

Markus's answer is the way people would normally do (and can be the preferred way since that would not pollute the main namespace). But that is not a solution to what you want. In order to do that you want, you usually implement the method on `Kernel`.

```
module Kernel
  def list_cars(first_car, second_car)
    puts "My father has two cars - a #{first_car.car_make} #{first_car.car_model} and a #{second_car.car_make} #{second_car.car_model}."
  end
end
```